# The origin on why '%20' is used as a space in URLs

Tags: url, encoding

I am interested in knowing why '%20' is used as a space in URLs, particularly why %20 was used and why we even need it in the first place.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's called [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Some characters can't be in a URI (for example `#`, as it denotes the URL fragment), so they are represented with characters that can be (`#` becomes `%23`)

Here's an excerpt from that same article:

> When a character from the reserved set (a "reserved character") has
>   special meaning (a "reserved purpose") in a certain context, and a URI
>   scheme says that it is necessary to use that character for some other
>   purpose, then the character must be *percent-encoded*.
>   **Percent-encoding a reserved character involves converting the
>   character to its corresponding byte value in ASCII and then
>   representing that value as a pair of hexadecimal digits.** The digits,
>   preceded by a percent sign ("%") which is used as an escape character,
>   are then used in the URI in place of the reserved character. (For a
>   non-ASCII character, it is typically converted to its byte sequence in
>   UTF-8, and then each byte value is represented as above.)

The space character's character code is `32`:

```
> ' '.charCodeAt(0)
32
```

Which is `20` in base-16:

```
> ' '.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
"20"
```

Tack a percent sign in front of it and you get `%20`.

Comment: Is it therefore completely legitimate to use spaces in file names for the internet, so long as they're correctly percentage encoded?

Comment: Sure, that's what percent encoding is for.

Answer (score 2):

Because URLs have strict syntactic rules, like `/` being a special path separator character, spaces not being allowed in a URL and all characters having to be a certain subset of ASCII. To embed arbitrary characters in URLs regardless of these restrictions, bytes can be percent encoded. The byte `x20` represents a space in the ASCII encoding (and most other encodings), hence `%20` is the URL-encoded version of it.

Answer (score 1):

It uses percent encoding. You can see the [Percent Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12) part of the RFC for [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
> component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
> allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
> component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
> triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
> hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For
> example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet
> "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space
> character (SP).