# Are URL encodings part of any language?

Tags: javascript, url, encoding

I googled it, and came up with:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

[The origin on why '%20' is used as a space in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900835/the-origin-on-why-20-is-used-as-a-space-in-urls)

[URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

and it appears to be part of an RFC spec. but not part of any language spec.

Maybe it is JavaScript.  I don't know.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

URL encodings are not specifically a part of the spec of any programming language, it's a RFC standard. However, URL encoding functions are available in almost all major programming languages. A non-exhaustive list of URL encoding functions in various languages:

- **JavaScript**: use `encodeURIComponent` for encoding a normal string, and `encodeURI` for encoding a full address. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/4414003) for more information.
- **Python 2**: `urllib.quote`
- **Python 3**: `urllib.parse.quote`
- **PHP**: `urlencode`
- **Java**: `java.net.URLEncoder.encode`
- **Ruby**: `CGI.escape`

Comment: javascript one is `encodeURIComponent`with a lower cased `e`. Also it's for uri parameters encoding. For url encoding, one should prefer `encodeURI`. [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Answer (score 0):

See the [URL standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) in general and the [Percent-encoded bytes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encoded-bytes) section in particular.